# How to show menu item icons using Action Bar Compat (api 8+). Are not shown

Tags: android

Using Action Bar Compat support library, I have noticed that the settings menu (3 dots) does not show the icons with each item. The xml is correctly configured (`android:icon="@drawable/ic_item"`) but the problem occurs running my app with emulator (v2.2) and real device (v2.2).

The contextual menu only displays the text items without their icons.

However, if I run the app in a real device with v4.0+, the icons are shown correctly with the text items of the contextual menu.

Any idea to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: "I have noticed that the settings menu (3 dots) does not show the icons with each item" -- it is not supposed to show the icons. The overflow does not have icons.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow menu does not have icons by design by Google. This is the proper (or at least standard) way for it to behave.